# How to rename a href="" or internal links/url dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have links on the web that are dynamically added, what I want to do is modify those urls to others (I want all links  inside my website to get modified).

I want to change them from this:

```
<a href="www.example.com/page-example-1.php">
```

To this:

```
<a href="www.example.com/page-example-1">
```

I want to remove that `.php` from all my actual internal links

This is my php code that creates links dynamically this code have the function to next/prev episode:

```
$pinfo = pathinfo($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]);
$reqpath = dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

if(preg_match("/(.*?)(\d+)\.php/", $pinfo["basename"], $matches)) {
  $fnbase = $matches[1];
  $fndir = $pinfo["dirname"];
  $current = intval($matches[2]);
  $next = $current + 1;
  $prior = $current - 1;
  $next_file = $fndir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fnbase . $next . ".php";
  $prior_file = $fndir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fnbase . $prior . ".php";
  if(!file_exists($next_file)) $next_file = false;
  if(!file_exists($prior_file)) $prior_file = false;

  if($prior_file) {
    $link = $reqpath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($prior_file);
    echo "<a class=\"btn btn-ep-left\" href=\"$link\">&laquo; Prev</a>";
  }
  if($next_file) {
    $link = $reqpath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($next_file);
    echo "<a class=\"btn btn-ep-right\" href=\"$link\">Siguente Next &raquo;</a>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Change the part that adds these links to format them they way you need.

Comment: if i do that , my code get crash

Comment: If you put valid links and do it correctly, your code should work.

Comment: i will add my php code to see it and your  will tell me other thingh

Comment: i edited my code take a look @PM77-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way (see comments):

```
// Get all links
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

links.forEach((link) => {
  // Check if link href ends with ".php"
  if(link.href.slice(-4) = ".php") {
    // Remove ".php"
    link.href = link.href.slice(0,-4);
  }
});
```

Comment: i want to chage the links before google crawl my links this work for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "before google crawl my links"?

Comment: yes but , however i solved it adding some code inside php